# MATLAB is using wrong dependency (files with the same name in different directories)

Tags: matlab, path

I'm trying to adapt a MATLAB script. I have the original code in a folder and the new version in another:

> dev\original 
>   dev\new

The new folder has all the original files and a few more. But one of the functions dependencies in one of the files in the new folder is calling the file in the original folder by mistake.

> File: 
>   dev\new\example.m
>
> Dependency Report: 
>   current dir         :  file_1 
>   current dir         :  file_2 
>   other               :  file_3

Even though there are "file_1", "file_2" and "file_3" in both folders.

> dev\original\file_1.m 
>   dev\original\file_2.m 
>   dev\original\file_3.m
>
> dev\new\file_1.m 
>   dev\new\file_2.m 
>   dev\new\file_3.m

Is there a way to force MATLAB to call the correct file? Or maybe only allow it to call files from the current and sub directories?

**Edit**:
To ilustrate more information, I ran the "pwd" and "which -all" commands to show that MATLAB knows the existence of both files and is running in the "new" folder.

```
>> pwd

ans =

     'C:\dev\new'

>> which -all file_3
Not on MATLAB path   % model constructor
C:\dev\new\file_3.m  % Shadowed
```

Comment: I've tested removing or renaming "dev\original\file_3.m" so that it does not conflict with "dev\original\file_3.m" and it works correctly. But I'm looking for a solution that does not rename or remove either file.

Comment: MATLAB uses a special [precedence order](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html) to determines which function to call when multiple functions in the current scope have the same name. Functions in the current folder take precedence over other functions on the path.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using [private](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/private-functions.html) folders where you control the scope of what your doing,

basically you put file_1, file_2 and file_3 in a `private` folder:

```
dev/new/example.m
dev/new/private/file_1.m
dev/new/private/file_2.m
dev/new/private/file_3.m
```

Then your example will call the file_*.m in the appropriate private folder.